# GmailApp.Search not returning emails in a date range

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to move emails to a label based on dates using a script. I am using the below code.

```
function addNaggingLabels() {
  var label = _getNaggingLabel();

  var threads = GmailApp.search('after:2018/4/30 before:2018/6/1 ');

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    label.addToThread(threads[i]);
  }
}
```

When I run this it should be marking all emails I received in May 2018 however when I look in my inbox I can see it is marking 4 out of the 7 emails I have in the inbox. It successfully marks emails from the 24, 29, and 31 but does not mark other emails I received or responded to on the 11 and the 16. Why would this be?

If I update the code to this:

```
function addNaggingLabels() {
  var label = _getNaggingLabel();

  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox after:2018/4/30 before:2018/6/1 ');

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    label.addToThread(threads[i]);
  }
}
```

It successfully marks all of the emails in my inbox, but now I have the issue of all the emails received within those dates that are not in my inbox.

Comment: I am using conversation view

Comment: Does this behavior persist if you use the `Gmail` "advanced service" instead of the `GmailApp`?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is useful for your situation, how about using "OR" for the 2nd query like ``{in:inbox (after:after:2018/4/30 before:2018/6/1)}``? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

Comment: @tehhowch Yes when I search in Gmail with that expression it does include the emails I am trying to label. I do not know if there is a limit as to how far it searches before it stops but I may be hitting a limit where it stops searching because of the volume of emails I received in May. If that is the case I would hope there is a way to bypass that

Comment: @Tanaike That would work if I run it that way I am afraid there are still emails that may be in the date range I would be missing.

Comment: @Derek the advanced service `Gmail`, which implements the Gmail REST API as an only-available-if-you-opt-in client library (shortcut `Gmail`) is not the same thing as the web Gmail interface. Please review "Apps Script advanced services" in your internet search engine of choice

Comment: I'm sorry I had misunderstand about the query. How about this one? ``{(in:inbox after:2018/4/30 before:2018/6/1) (after:2018/4/30 before:2018/6/1)}``

Comment: @tehhowch I misread your first comment. I went in and enabled the Advanced Services but am still seeing the same issue.

Comment: I am certain now though that it is because the Search stops after 500 emails are found. I am not sure if there is a way to increase this.

Comment: @Derek you can simply use more date spans

Comment: You can do batched calls by using another overload of the 'search' method. GmailApp.search(query, start, max);  Just keep updating the start index until threads.length is less than max (500)

Comment: What about creating a Filter and labeling emails, then use var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Bounce");